# Can't install KDE on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, kde

When i type `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` i get the following:-

```
timetraveller@timetraveller-to-be-filled-by-o-e-m:~$     sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: ark but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: baloo-kf5 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dolphin but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kde-cli-tools but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kde-spectacle but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: khelpcenter but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: khotkeys but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kinfocenter but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kio but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kio-extras but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kmenuedit but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: ksysguard but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kwin
                   Depends: kwrited but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: okular but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: powerdevil but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: sddm-theme-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: systemsettings but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: akregator but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: amarok but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: baloo-utils but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: bluedevil but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: dragonplayer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: frameworkintegration but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gstreamer-qapt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gtk3-engines-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gwenview but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ibus-qt4 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: k3b but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kaddressbook but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kate but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kcalc but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-config-gtk-style but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-config-sddm but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-config-whoopsie but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-telepathy but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdeconnect-plasma but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdenetwork-filesharing but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdepim-runtime but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kimageformat-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kio-mtp but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kmail but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: knotes but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: konsole but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kontact but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: konversation but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: korganizer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: krdc but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kscreen but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ksshaskpass but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ksystemlog but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ktorrent but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-driver-manager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-notification-helper but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kwalletmanager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kwin-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libqt5qml-graphicaleffects but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: milou but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: okular-extra-backends but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: partitionmanager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: phonon-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: pinentry-qt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-dataengines-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-discover-updater but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-nm but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-pa but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-runners-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-wallpapers-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: polkit-kde-agent-1 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: print-manager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: qapt-deb-installer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: qt5-image-formats-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: skanlite but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: user-manager but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
timetraveller@timetraveller-to-be-filled-by-o-e-m:~$
```

My */etc/apt/sources.list* contains (full contents here - https://pastebin.com/wybNsDth):

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
```

Comment: It seems you have malformed *sources.list* file. Put the contents of your */etc/apt/sources.list* to the question.

Comment: It was too long so i pasted it here:-https://pastebin.com/wybNsDth

I really appreciate your help

Comment: The *sources.list* file look OK. Try `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` to resume package installation and fix broken packages.

Comment: i did it, and got this 
https://pastebin.com/g9SEUtyC

Comment: Try to install software-properties-kde manually with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-kde`. And start over.

Comment: I get this https://pastebin.com/9cVDFRCV
I am sorry to be such a drag, and appreciate the help

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy python3-software-properties`. Do you have any PPA enabled?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RqRKfxmg

i get this as output of it

Comment: if its any help, i easily installed xfce but cant install kde :(

Comment: python3-software-properties 0.96.20.7 is from xenial-updates, but your system does not indicate this. Try to delete APT package-lists with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, then clean APT cache with `sudo apt-get clean`, update lists `sudo apt-get update` and start over.

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much sir! I really really appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following actions fixed the problem for the OP:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```